# How detailed are GUI test cases in real projects?

Tags: user-interface, testing

Let's say I need to test a main page of a crm system. It has a menu and many elements on the page. My undestanding is prior to checking the functionality it's needed to test the GUI. Do I write a test case for each link/element to check their presence as per specification? A test case for each element to check that they are correctly aligned and responsive? Or is it enough to just say in one test case that everything is at its place and all the links work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's lots of ways to test the main page of a CRM system. But before you do that, what is your goal or testing mission? Based on your mission, it will inform how you test and what tests you select to run. As an example of tests you can run:

- Specification-Based Testing (confirming specifications have been met)
- Functional Testing (Testing individual / complete functions)
- UI/UX Testing (Testing to understand how easy the UI is to navigate or how well designed the user experience is)

You can't test everything, so you need to figure out what is most important to test at this time and then that becomes your mission. You'll have to determine the best way to document and support your testing in a way that helps you test and can be done in a timely manner.